# VSCode for WSL: wrong python version of the interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to use VScode for Python for Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). On the bottom left corner, I see that the python version is 3.6 (which is what I want):

[image]

However, when I check the version:

```
print(sys.version)
```

I get 2.7.17. Why I can't use Python 3 and how can I switch the interpreter to Python 3.6.9?

Comment: How are you executing that code to check the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways. The most easy one is adding a shebang on top of your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Also, did you run the code using `python mycode.py` or `python3 mycode.py`. It makes a difference.

Another way is to follow this tutorial to install and use different versions of python. https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/

Another way is to use virtual environments. That way you can define your python version on project level. There are probably more ways.

Comment: This `alias python=python3` is a very bad suggestion. I believe that there is still some software that depends on Python 2. Never do such aliases!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are probably right. Updated the answer.